# row in screen is not deleted after I changed the quantity to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can figure out how to update the json or the view to have the row with the *** remove after I had click Update the quantity link.

I want the line to be delete and the view to be refresh without it.
Here is the output and the code.

I think the idea is to re-execute in the controller the RemoveFromCart Action Result.

I tried this return RedirectToAction("RemoveFromCart", new { id = id });
I also tried this RedirectToAction ("Panier/RemoveFromCart", new { id = id });

I was expecting the controller to branch to RemoveFromCart and execute it but it seems just to 
sent back to my view again without executing the code of RemoveFromCart.

The only way I found to execute the code was with:
int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

Any idea?

Output

```
Cart

Baseball glove has been remove from the cart

Payment >>
-----------

Add another article >>
----------------------

Product          Price     Quantity

Toaster          25.00       2         Update Quantity >>       Remove from Cart >>
                                       ------------------       -------------------

Baseball Glove   39.99       0         Update Quantity >>       Remove from Cart >>    *****
                                       ------------------       -------------------

Total                                  50.00
```

Expected Output

```
Cart

Baseball glove has been remove from the cart

Payment >>
-----------

Add another article >>
----------------------

Product          Price     Quantity

Toaster          25.00       2         Update Quantity >>       Remove from Cart >>
                                       ------------------       -------------------

Total                                  50.00
```

PanierController.cs

```
        // AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
    {
        object results = null;
        // Remove the item from the cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        try
        {
            // Get the name of the product to display the message
            string produitDescription = dbProduit.Paniers
                .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.Description;

            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

            // Display the confirmation message
            results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(produitDescription) +
                    " a été retiré de votre panier.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };
        }
        catch
        {
            results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = "le panier a déjà été vidé.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = 0                   
            };
        }

        return Json(results);

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCartCount(int id, int cartCount)
    {
        ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel results = null;
        try 
        { 
             // Get the cart 
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the product to display confirmation 
             string productName = dbProduit.Paniers
                 .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.Description;

             int idProduit = dbProduit.Paniers
                 .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.ProduitId;

          /*   int nbrPanier = cart.GetCount(); */

             var prd = dbProduit.Produits.Single(produit => produit.ProduitId == idProduit);

             if (prd.Quantite - cartCount < 0)
             {
                 string msg = "Erreur la quantité dépasse celle de l'inventaire du produit, 
                             veuillez réduire la quantité ou choisir un autre produit";
                 results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
                 {
                     Message = msg,
                     CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                     CartCount = cart.GetCount()
                 };
             }

             else
                 if (cartCount > 0)

                    {
                        // Update the cart count 
                        int itemCount = cart.UpdateCartCount(id, cartCount);

                        //Prepare messages
                        string msg = "La quantité de " + Server.HtmlEncode(productName) + " a été
                                      ajusté dans le panier.";
                        if (itemCount == 0) msg = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) + " a été enlevé 
                             de votre panier.";
                        //
                        // Display the confirmation message 
                        results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
                        {
                            Message = msg,
                            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                            CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                            ItemCount = itemCount,
                            DeleteId = id
                        };
                    }
                 else
                 {

                      /* RedirectToAction("Panier/RemoveFromCart", new { id = id });  */ 
                      /* return RedirectToAction ("Panier/RemoveFromCart", new { id = id }); */

                     int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);
                     results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
                     {
                         Message = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) + " a été retiré de votre 
                                       panier.",
                         CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                         CartCount = cart.GetCount()
                     };

                 }
        }
        catch 
        {
            results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = "Une erreur est survenue ou données en entrée erronnées...",
                CartTotal = -1,
                CartCount = -1,
                ItemCount = -1,
                DeleteId = id
            };
        }
        return Json(results);
    }
```

ShoppingCart.cs

```
    public int GetCount()
    {
        // Get the count of each item in the cart and sum them up
        int? count = (from cartItems in db.Paniers
                      where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                      select (int?)cartItems.Quantite).Sum();
        // Return 0 if all entries are null
        return count ?? 0;
    }
    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        // Multiply album price by count of that album to get 
        // the current price for each of those albums in the cart
        // sum all album price totals to get the cart total
        decimal? total = (from cartItems in db.Paniers
                          where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                          select (int?)cartItems .Quantite *
                          cartItems.Produit.Prix).Sum();

        return total ?? decimal.Zero;
    }

    public int UpdateCartCount(int id, int cartCount)
    {
        // Get the cart 
        var cartItem = db.Paniers.Single(
            cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId
            && cart.PanierId == id);

        int itemCount = 0;

        if (cartItem != null)
        {
            if (cartCount > 0)
            {

                cartItem.Quantite = cartCount;
                itemCount = cartItem.Quantite;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Paniers.Remove(cartItem);
            }
            // Save changes 
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return itemCount;
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 { 
 <h3>
     <em>Visualisation </em> du panier:

     @if (TempData["err_message"] != null)
     {
         @TempData["err_message"]
     }

 </h3>

 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart","Panier")',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).remove();
                     $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                     $('#cart-status').text('Panier (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                     $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                     $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                     $.get('@Url.Action("CartSummary", "Panier")');
                     $('#content').html(result);
                 },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                  }
             });
             return false;
         });
     });

     $(function () {
         $(".RefreshQuantity").click(function () {
             // Get the id from the link 
             var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("data-id");

             var countToUpdate = 0;
             if ($("#" + $(this).attr("id")).val() !== '') {
                 countToUpdate = $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).val();
             }
             if (recordToUpdate != '') {        
                 // Perform the ajax post 
                 $.post("/Panier/UpdateCartCount", { "id": recordToUpdate, "cartCount": 
                          countToUpdate },
                 function (data) {
                    // Successful requests get here 
                    // Update the page elements                        
                    if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                        $('#row-' + data. DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    $('#update-message').text(htmlDecode(data.Message));
                    $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    //Only process the callback data when no server error occurs
                    if (data.ItemCount != -1) {
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Panier (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    }
                 }
             );
           }
        });
     });

     $(function () {
         if (typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
             String.prototype.trim = function () {
                 return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
             }
         }
     });

     function clearUpdateMessage() {
         // Reset update-message area
         $('#update-message').text('');
     }

     function htmlDecode(value) {
         if (value) {
             return $('<div />').html(value).text();
         }
         else {
             return '';
         }
     }
 </script>



 <div>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
{ 
    <p>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CartItems[i].Quantite)
    </p> 
}
 </div>

 <div id="update-message" style="color:red;" >

 </div>

 <div id="content">
     @if (Model.CartTotal != 0)
     {
         <p class="button">
             @Html.ActionLink("Paiement >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
         </p>
         <p class="NouvelAjout">
             @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter un autre article >>", "Magasin", "Home")
         </p>
     }

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Produit
        </th>
        <th>
            Prix (unitaire)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantite
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @{int ix = 0;}

    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                       item.ProduitId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Produit.Prix
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Quantite, 
                    new  {style = "width:30px; text-align:right;",
                    onkeyup = "clearUpdateMessage();",
                    onchange = "clearUpdateMessage();"
                    }) 
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200px">
                <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity" data-id="@item.PanierId" 
                   id="CartItems_@(ix)__Quantite"> Mettre à jour la quantité >> <a />
            </td>

            <td style ="width: 200px">
                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier >> 
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ix++;
    }

    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="cart-total">
            @Model.CartTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </div>

 }
```